# React Native Recording issue with iOS even after compression

Tags: react-native, audio-recording

I am facing issue in recording doctor patient conversation in react native iOS while uploading the file even after compressing the file using AAC method as the audio file size limit is 25 MB for whisper api to process speech to text. I am not getting the output.

Tried compression of file before uploading to whisper api

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.